# Why does relative path of project files auto-resolve to c:\windows while executing the build in release mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, runtime-error

So, I have completed a C# console application using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.
I have a local file within the project folder. Within my code, I have performed a log writing operation by assigning the relative path of this file to a string variable. The file was created during the first build/run and then appended with information during further runs.

```
string rpath = "..\\LogFile2.txt";
```

I built this project in debug mode and ran it. During this run the rpath is correctly identified as

```
c:\project_app_folder\bin\LogFile2.txt
```

However, while building this project in release mode and then scheduling the .exe file to run at a particular time in the windows task scheduler, I get a run-time error saying

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\local\pic'.

How do I resolve this? I want the temporary folders or text files created during run time to be part of my project folder/package?

Please also note , I cannot put absolute paths as this code will have to be packaged and sent to another user and that user may chose to store the program in a location he/she sees fit.

Comment: I don't think it's "release mode" that is the cause of your issues here - I think it's running it as a scheduled task, where it probably defaults to a working directory of `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: This issue is not because of release mode, when the scheduler invokes the program the working directory will be different as @Damien_The_Unbeliever said. you can use the start in option to specify your directory

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not because of release mode, when the scheduler invokes the program the working directory will be different as @Damien_The_Unbeliever said. you can use the "start in" option when you specify your action, as your release directory.

> The "start in" is mainly to make sure that if you have relative paths
>   in the task to run, it understands which directory to use.